# How to store query output in temp db?

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

I am really new to the programming but I am studying it. I have one problem which I don't know how to solve. 
I have collection of docs in mongoDB and I'm using Elasticsearch to query the fields. The problem is I want to store the output of search back in mongoDB but in different DB. I know that I have to create temporary DB which has to be updated with every search result. But how to do this? Or give me documentation to read so I could learn it. I will really appreciate your help!

Comment: look at this. This could be of some help .http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2009/01/04/managing-tempdb-in-sql-server-tempdb-configuration.aspx

Comment: but what to do in case with NoSQL DB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mongo does not natively support "temp" collections.

A typical thing to do here is to not actually write the entire results output to another DB since that would be utterly pointless since Elasticsearch does its own caching as such you don't need any layer over the top.

As well, due to IO concerns it is normally a bad idea to write say a result set of 10k records to Mongo or another DB.

There is a feature request for what you talk of: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3215 but no planning as of yet.

#### Example

You could have a table of results.

Within this table you would have a doc that looks like:

```
{keywords: ['bok', 'mongodb']}
```

Each time you search and scroll through each result item you would write a row to this table populating the keywords field with keywords from that search result. This would be per search result per search result list per search. It would probably be best to just stream each search result to MongoDB as they come in. I have never programmed Python (though I wish to learn) so an example in pseudo:

```
var elastic_results = [{'elasticresult'}];
foreach(elastic_results as result){
    //split down the phrases in this result and make a keywords array
    db.results_collection.insert(array_formed_from_splitting_down_result); // Lets just lazy insert no need for batch or trying to shrink the amount of data to one go or whatever, lets just stream it in.
}
```

So as you go along your results you basically just mass insert as fast a possible create a sort of "stream" of input to MongoDB. It can do this quite well.

This should then give you a shardable list of words and language verbs to process things like MRs on and stuff to aggregate statistics about them.

Without knowing more and more about your scenario this is pretty much my best answer.

This does not use the temp table concept but instead makes your data permanent which is fine by the sounds of it since you wish to use Mongo as a storage engine for further tasks.

Comment: is there anyway to store the output as .txt file ? Coz I need just extract that output results for further natural language processing

Comment: Yea just pump the cursor returned from elasticsearch into your languages fopen (I am not sure what server side language you use). Pumping with reduced memory to a text file should do the trick, plus it'd be much easier to segment your files across many shards. I mean how many results are you expecting cos if MongoDb is solely being used for this reason (to store results for language processing) it could be used, just not temp tables.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate your help! At last can you recommend me some documentation for that? Just newbie and still have more to learn)

Comment: What language are you using? PHP/Java/C#/C++? The general docs can be found on the Mongo site: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Home Other than that it is upto your particular implementation as to further details. If you need help with understand schema etc or concept (when you've solidified it a bit more) just ask a question :)

Comment: Added something of a possible solution to your problem. I don't know mcuh about your use case but hopefully it might help.

Comment: I am using Python with its NLTK. So that is why I wanted to store in .txt format. Anyway thanks. I will read a lot of paper to found out the way)

Comment: Indeed only problem with txt is that you got no indexes or fast method querying unlike Mongo. I just had a brain storm, your basically making a dictionary for use on language processing. Others have done this, try searching for "mongodb dictionary" on google also try similar searches on mongodb-user I have seen this type of question before. Anyway hope it works out :)

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! You might think that I am completely dump but can you explain how to stream back each result to MongoDB? I mean if the results are short text like this:"text":"Can't wait to see Brave when I get back to SF! Just watched The Muppet Movie on the flight - same overwhelming emotions :) Loved it! @damoxy" how can I stream it back to mongoDB?

Comment: Yeah I am doing sentiment analysis using Python NLTK. After getting the output text for further  sentiment analysis it has to be stored somewhere to use it as  corpora for analyzer

Comment: I have never programmed Python (though I wish to) and nor have I done corpora or NLTK so it's starting to get out of my water here but I have appended some code to my answer.

Comment: Hey sorry for asking again, but what would be the write way to write your code in Mongo Shell?

Comment: I don't think it is possible since ElasticSearch does not have a JS driver compatible with the MongoDB JS driver. Since you would rquire getting the results from Python and ElasticSearch API exists in Python I would personally just code straight to Python

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is MongoDB river plugin to work with Elasticsearch...

Answer (score 0):

`db.your_table.find().forEach(function(doc) { b.another_table.insert(doc); } );`