# how to push the result into DB?

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

I need some help with that...I want to store the results of query from Elasticsearch in mongodb. So am I doing write? Origin of code took from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11120060/how-to-store-query-output-in-temp-db/11168302#11168302)

```
    var elastic_results = [{'elasticresult'}];
forEach(elastic_results){db.results_collection.insert();}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i = 0; i < elastic_results.length; i++){
    db.results_collection.insert(elastic_results[i]);
}
```

By the way if your gonna steal my code from another post I made can you at least link it instead of calling the code your own?

Comment: you can make that link, too ;-)

Comment: that requires effort though :) though it is more of a sort of notice to him that it's not nice to just steal.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't mean to steal. I forgot to link back to that page. Hope you didn't get it wrong...

Comment: What is the meaning of i here? I am getting this error  ReferenceError: elastic_results is not defined (shell):1

Comment: Your getting that error because the variable is not defined. You are trying to get this working from shell however you cannot without serious modifications to the shell itself. It is better to get this working in your own server side language instead.

Comment: @Aikin: 'What is the meaning of i?' If you don't know how a really normal looking for-loop works then you may be a little bit out of your depth. I would suggest you find yourself a descent introductory programming tutorial and work through that, once you understand program flow and how variables work then continue. Otherwise you will have quite a tough time

Comment: oh thank yo...yeah you are right im new bee and it's difficult for me...can you suggest any useful tutorial?